# Error messages from model in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Currently my app includes the following code ***to display the error messages on a view  from model.rb*** but it is not updated code as `error_messages_for` is deprecated in Rails 3. Can anyone please suggest me how to do the same in Rails 3?? I want the logic to be in model.rb file and from there I should be able to display error msgs on view

**excel_file.rb(model.rb)**

```
#jus some sample function
def show_error(test_file)
    if test_file == 'Upload Test Case'
      errors[:base] << "Please upload excel sheet with testsuite config sheet and testcases" 
    elsif test_file == 'Upload Test Data'
      errors[:base] << "Please upload excel sheet with test data" 
    end
  end
```

**sampleview.html.erb**

```
 #some code..
   <span class='error'><%= error_messages_for (@excel_file) %></span>
     #some code..
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
def error_messages_for(*objects)
  html = ""
  objects = objects.map {|o| o.is_a?(String) ? instance_variable_get("@#{o}") : o}.compact
  errors = objects.map {|o| o.errors.full_messages}.flatten
  if errors.any?
    html << "<div id='errorExplanation'><ul>\n"
    errors.each do |error|
      html << "<li>#{h error}</li>\n"
    end
    html << "</ul></div>\n"
  end
  html.html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Create a shared partial

app/views/common/_error_messages.html.erb:

```
<% if target.errors.any? %>  
<div id="errorExplanation">  
  <h2><%= pluralize(target.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this record from being saved:</h2>  
  <ul>  
  <% target.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>  
    <li><%= msg %></li>  
  <% end %>  
  </ul>  
</div>  
<% end %>
```

*And call it like this:(in sampleview.html.erb)*

```
<% if @excel_file %>
    <%= render "common/error_messages", :target => @excel_file %>
<% end %>
```

Put up the if condition to avoid the error NoMethodError:Undefined method 'errors' in target.errors.any?. This avoids the page from throwing this error and renders the partial view only when an instance of target(@excel_file) is present.

This works for custom validations the same way

In excel_file.rb(model.erb) in app/model:

def show_error
  if test_file == 'Upload Test Case'
    errors[:base] << "Please upload excel sheet with testsuite config sheet and testcases" 
  elsif test_file == 'Upload Test Data'
    errors[:base] << "Please upload excel sheet with test data" 
  end
end

This worked perfectly! Now I'm able to get the error notifications properly :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use https://github.com/rails/dynamic_form.

It provides the functionality you want.

**Update**

You are right, this is not in accordance to Rails 3.

You should probably do something like this:

Create a shared partial

**/app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb**

```
<% if target.errors.any? %>  
<div id="errorExplanation">  
  <h2><%= pluralize(target.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this record from being saved:</h2>  
  <ul>  
  <% target.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>  
    <li><%= msg %></li>  
  <% end %>  
  </ul>  
</div>  
<% end %>
```

And call it like this:

```
<%= render "shared/error_messages", :target => @excel_file %>
```

So why are the methods `error_messages_for` and `f.error_messages` removed? Ryan bates says the following:

> The reason that the methods have been removed is that the display of the error messages often needs to be customized and doing this through the old methods was a little bit cumbersome and not as flexible as having the error message HTML inline as we have now. Having the HTML to hand in the views means that we can change the display of the error messages however we like.

source: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3

**Update 2**

This works for custom validations the same way

```
validate :show_error

def show_error
  if test_file == 'Upload Test Case'
    errors[:base] << "Please upload excel sheet with testsuite config sheet and testcases" 
  elsif test_file == 'Upload Test Data'
    errors[:base] << "Please upload excel sheet with test data" 
  end
end
```

Comment: But is it in accordance with Rails 3.2??

Comment: No it's not. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.. I'll integrate this with my app and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: Can you tell me how can I add my error messages in the model.rb file? the asciicasts u mentioned talks only about in built error msgs or customized if done using 'validates' . My code validates the uploaded file through some logic . Eg:
if some_condition
   <show this error msg>

So should it be done by using errors[:base] like before or is there anything new in Rails 3??

Comment: You are talking about custom validations which might be outside the scope of this question, but I will add it to my answer..

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel like my answer solved your problem. Consider marking my answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: It is giving the following error:
 NoMethodError in Account#upload_file

Showing D:/WS/som/app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
Please help!

Comment: Did you specify the target when rendering the view? `<%= render "shared/error_messages", :target => @excel_file %>`. Make sure @excel_file is set and not nil.

Comment: Yeah I have specified that.. Its taking the target and throwing error on 'errors' method.. in if target.errors.any?

Comment: Hi, the problem was it was trying to render the error even while loading the page. so the error! Now i changed the logic to render that partial view only if an instance of model is present. It worked! I'll update the same in your answer so that it helps others :)..